# jQuery Dialog issue with close and load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a jQuery dialog that loads another page inside.
Well, it works fine only the first time, if I try to open again the dialog, the Chrome Developer Tools shows this:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

and the dialog does not open.

Here is the jQuery code that I have:

```
$(function() {

  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     title: 'Dettagli contratto',
     height: 150,
     width:350
  });


  $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).load( "contracts.php" );
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });


});
```

I think that the problem is the load() function. In fact, if I remove this function it works fine.

Any helps? Thank you!

Comment: jQuery adds elements when you call `dialog()` so as to actually make a dialog. When you call `load()` you replace all that with new content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect that your `contracts.php` contains the jQuery script tag very similar to `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. So whenever you load your `contracts.php` in a dialog; all the previously initialized widgets/plugins gets wiped out.

To overcome this; try to remove jQuery script tag from your `contracts.php` and see what you get.

Comment: @L.Soprano - was that helpful...?

Comment: So load can now execute script too?